# Laravel API: Load nested relationship in resource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I've got 3 models: `Order`, `OrderItem` and `Product` (for simplicity just showing the relationships):

```
class Order extends BaseModel
{
    use Uuid;

    protected $casts = [
        'status' => OrderStatuses::class,
    ];

    /**
     * An Order has multiple OrderItems associated to it.
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function orderItems(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
```

```
class OrderItem extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * Get the Order the OrderItem belongs to.
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function order(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class)
                ->withDefault();
    }

    /**
     * Get the product associated to this OrderItem.
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function product(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

```
class Product extends BaseModel
{
    use Uuid;

    /**
     * Get the category the product belongs to.
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

with their respective DB tables:

```
orders: id, status, subtotal, total 
order_items: id, order_id, product_id, qty, price, total
products: id, name, slug, sku, description, price
```

I've got only a controller for `Order` and `Product` but I do have resources for all 3:

```
class OrdersResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => (string)$this->id,
            'type' => 'orders',
            'attributes' => [
                'status' => ($this->status)->value(),
                'payment_type' => $this->payment_type,
                'payment_transaction_no' => $this->payment_transaction_no,
                'subtotal' => $this->subtotal,
                'taxes'  => $this->taxes,
                'total' => $this->total,
                'items' => OrderItemsResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('orderItems')),
                'created_at' => $this->created_at,
                'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

```
class ProductsResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request) : array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'type' => 'products',
            'attributes' => [
                'barcode' => $this->barcode,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'slug' => $this->slug,
                'sku' => $this->sku,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'type' => $this->type,
                // todo return  category object?
                'category' => new CategoriesResource($this->whenLoaded('category')),
                'wholesale_price' => $this->wholesale_price,
                'retail_price' => $this->retail_price,
                'base_picture' => ($this->base_picture ? asset('images/products/' . $this->base_picture) : null),
                'current_stock_level' => $this->current_stock_level,
                'active' => $this->active,
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

```
class OrderItemsResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'order_id' => $this->order_id,
            'product_id' =>  $this->product_id,
            'qty' => $this->qty,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'total' => $this->total,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

When hitting my orders controller I return the data (in this case for displaying an order) like this:

```
public function show(Order $order): JsonResponse
    {
        return (new OrdersResource($order->loadMissing('orderItems')))
            ->response()
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

So far so go, the order is returned like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
        "type": "orders",
        "attributes": {
            "status": "new",
            "payment_type": "",
            "payment_transaction_no": "",
            "subtotal": 71000,
            "taxes": 0,
            "total": 71000,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "product_id": "444b0f3-2b12-45ab-3434-4453121231ad51",
                    "order_id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
                    "qty": 10,
                    "price": 200,
                    "total": 2000,
                    "created_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:07.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-11-05T16:28:02.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "product_id": "324b0f3-2b12-45ab-3434-12312330ad50",
                    "order_id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
                    "qty": 3,
                    "price": 23000,
                    "total": 69000,
                    "created_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:29.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:29.000000Z"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-11-05T16:28:02.000000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

but now I'm in need of returning the actual product as part of `OrderItem` instead of just the product ID, so I updated my resource to include:
`'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),`

my resource ended up looking like this:

```
public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'order_id' => $this->order_id,
            'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
            'qty' => $this->qty,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'total' => $this->total,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

yet the product is not visible in my response, what am I missing? Isn't that the right way to load it? do i need to load it from my controller?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've updated the relationship in `OrderItem`, now it looks like the following:

```
public function product(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Where `id` points to the `id` column in `products` table, and `product_id` is the FK in `order_item`.

At this point if I do the following:

```
// just get any orderItem
$orderItem = OrderItem::first();
dd($orderItem->product);
```

I do see that the relationship is working because the product is being printed, but the object is still not part of the API response, meaning that in my resource this line is not working as expected:

```
'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
```

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the way I was trying to load `product` in the resource to be either of these two:

```
'product' => $this->load('product'),
```

```
'product' => $this->loadMissing('product'),
```

but that's giving me a nested object over the already nested one like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
        "type": "orders",
        "attributes": {
            "status": "new",
            "payment_type": "",
            "payment_transaction_no": "",
            "subtotal": 71000,
            "taxes": 0,
            "total": 71000,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "order_id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
                    "product": {
                        "id": 9,
                        "order_id": "20d9b0f3-2b32-45a7-8814-12c77210ad50",
                        "product_id": "f6bd3290-7748-49fa-8995-e0de47291fc9",
                        "qty": 10,
                        "price": 200,
                        "total": 2000,
                        "created_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:07.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2022-11-05T16:28:02.000000Z",
                        "product": {
                            "id": "f6bd3290-7748-49fa-8995-e0de47291fc9",
                            "barcode": "010101010101010101",
                            "name": "Test 5",
                            "slug": "test-5",
                            "sku": "t55te345c",
                            "description": "asd asd asd asd asd",
                            "type": "goods",
                            "category_id": 4,
                            "wholesale_price": 34,
                            "retail_price": 200,
                            "base_picture": null,
                            "current_stock_level": 0,
                            "active": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-09-23T16:29:18.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2022-09-23T22:00:40.000000Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "qty": 10,
                    "price": 200,
                    "total": 2000,
                    "created_at": "2022-11-05T16:26:07.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-11-05T16:28:02.000000Z"
                }
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

Notice how `product` now has all over again the data from `items`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
$order->loadMissing('orderItems.product')
```

Comment: nope, still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

1. Your `Product` model is missing the relationship to `OrderItem`.  You defined:

   ```
   // In OrderItem model
   public function product(): HasOne
   {
       return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id');
   }
   ```

   And you are missing [the required inverse relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship):

   ```
   // In Product model
   public function orderItem(): BelongsTo
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(OrderItem::class);
   }
   ```
2. It looks like your schema is incorrect.  Consider the [`hasOne()` example in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).  If a `User` `hasOne()` `Phone`, then:

   > In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key

   In terms of the schema, it means the `phones` table has a `user_id` column.  Compare that to your `OrderItem` which `hasOne()` `Product`.  The convention described in the example above means that the `products` table is expected to have an `order_item_id` column.  But it does not - you need to add that.

   Maybe you started this relationship around the other way (`Product` `hasOne` `OrderItem`), because you do have an `order_items.product_id` column - but that is not required with the relationships you have shown.  You should remove that field.
3. In the `OrderItem` model you have overruled the default foreign key and specified it as `id`:

   ```
   public function product(): HasOne
   {
       return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id');
   }
   ```

   This means the `id` column in the `products` table represents the OrderItem ID.  That doesn't make any sense, and I am guessing that is incorrect.  Just remove that `id` in the relationship, and the default conventions will mean Laravel will look for an `order_item_id` field in the `products` table, exactly as described in 2) above.

   ```
   public function product(): HasOne
   {
       return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
   }
   ```

   In my experience you almost never need to override Laravel's default foreign key conventions, unless you're doing something particularly strange.  Even then, it complicates things enough that it is maybe worth rethinking your schema just to get it to match the expected conventions!

Comment: makes sense. I added the inverse relationship but the result remains the same.

Comment: Do the relationships actually work? Eg in `tinker` can you load an OrderItem and view it's product? And vice-versa?

Comment: no, they are not working, not sure why. Perhaps there's something missing in the declaration?

Comment: thanks for updated response. Based on the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) one can define a one way relationship, right? I mean, not all relationships need to be defined both ways if not needed. In my case, I don't need it, so adding `order_item_id` to the `products` table wouldn't be a good design choice. I need to get the `products` related to an order (via `orderITem` -> `product_id`) but I don't care about the `orderItems` to which a product belongs to

Comment: I'm almost there but not quite yet, see my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. Thanks to both @Bob and @Don'tPanic whose answers pointed me in the right direction.

First I needed to correct my relationship definition in `OrderItem` model specifying both keys used in the current table and in the table where the related field is being used:

```
public function product(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
    }
```

but that itself was not being enough for my resource to return the expected data via this:

```
'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
```

I also needed to load the relationship in my controller:

```
public function show(Order $order): JsonResponse
    {
        return (new OrdersResource($order->loadMissing('orderItems', 'orderItems.product')))
            ->response()
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

That was the last step needed. Once again, thanks to both of you.